# How to union two spark Dataframes with a field of type struct that can differ?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, struct, apache-spark-sql

I'm quite new with Apache Spark and still struggling with it sometimes. I'm trying to import a quite complex JSON file and flatten it before saving it in a parquet file.

My JSON file is a tree of stores.

```
{
"id": "store02",
"name": "store name",
"domain": "domain",
"currency": "EUR",
"address1": "Somewhere",
"country": "GER",
"city": "Berlin",
"zipCode": "12345",
"timeZone": "CET",
"accounts" : [
    {
        "field1": "",
        "filed2": "",
        "field3": "",
        "optionnalArray1": [
            {
                "field1": "",
                "field2": ""
            }
        ],
        "optionnalArray2": ["aa", "bb"]
    }
],
"stores": [ .... ]    
}
```

Each store can have a field which is an array of accounts. An account has 3 mandatory fields and two optionals. So I have a dataframe with a field that can have 3 different types.

Importing the file in a dataframe is no big deal but during the flatten process I may want to do an union on two dataframes with accounts that may have a different schema and of course I have the following error:

> "Union can only be performed on tables with the compatible column types"

Is there a way to do this easily? How can spark import such JSON file without problem?

---

Let's say I have two dataframes. The first one is a dataframe of stores without accounts. The second one is a dataframe of stores with accounts. An account is a struct defined like that:

```
val acquirerStruct = StructType(
    StructField("merchantId", StringType, nullable = true) ::
    StructField("name", StringType, nullable = true) ::
    Nil)

val accountStruct = StructType(
    StructField("acquirers", ArrayType(acquirerStruct), nullable = true) ::
        StructField("applicationCode", StringType, nullable = true) ::
        StructField("channelType", StringType, nullable = true) ::
        StructField("id", StringType, nullable = true) ::
        StructField("terminals", ArrayType(StringType), nullable = true) ::
        Nil)
```

When I want to union the two dataframes I create a column account to my first dataframe before:

```
df1.withColumn("account", array(lit(null).cast(accountStruct))).union(df2)
```

If, in df2, all rows have an account that has the same structure that accountStruct it works fine. But that is not always true. An account may have no terminals or acquirers. That's perfectly valid in JSON. In that case I have the error mentioned before.

> "Union can only be performed on tables with the compatible column types"

Comment: can you share what you've tried so far. ??

Comment: you should add the following answer in the question itself. Please do so :)

Comment: ok. done. I didn't know it works this way.

Comment: can't you write an if else statement to check for account column in df2?

Comment: Yes I could but I would like to avoid that and have a code as simplest as possible. In fact I already have a workaround that is pretty much the same but I'm quite frustated to not be able to do such thing in one line of code and I don't understand why Spark seems perfectly able to deal with columns of such type and don't allows me to do the same.

Comment: I don't see any other easy way around than to create account column in df2 before joining if account column is not present in df2 :)

Answer (score 1):

In Spark 3 you can use:

```
df = df1.unionByName(df2, allowMissingColumns=True)
```

In Spark 2 you can use:

```
diff1 = [c for c in df2.columns if c not in df1.columns]
diff2 = [c for c in df1.columns if c not in df2.columns]
df = df1.select('*', *[F.lit(None).alias(c) for c in diff1]) \
    .unionByName(df2.select('*', *[F.lit(None).alias(c) for c in diff2]))
```

But I want to add that to make your life easy you should just but both JSON files in the same directory and then read them in and Spark will do the work for you.

```
val peopleDF = spark.read.json(path)
```

This will union the data and fill nulls for you at the same time. And in my opinion is the easiest way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in PySpark I solved it by providing schema when reading the incompatible dataframe

```
import copy
...
schema_to_read = copy.deepcopy(df1.schema)
df2 = sql_context.read.format("json").schema(schema_to_read).load(path)
```